# Browser Cookie Disabled, Sitecore behaviour

Tags: cookies

As we know, currently most sites depend on cookies being enabled in the browser, including Sitecore which handles personalization, tracking analytics etc.

- What if cookies are disabled?
- Do we really need to display a the message to end-user that the site uses Cookies?

Why are most of sites now, not displaying the message that browser Cookies are disabled?

Comment: You mean the user disables the cookie browser?

Comment: Yes, user disables the cookie in browser.

Comment: The current way that it functions is that all sites that make use of cookie provide a popup on top or bottom of the page saying something like “This site is using cookie for better user experience. Disabling cookie may have some feature not working properly.” So, this is making the user aware that he needs to have cookie enabled for better experience.

Comment: This is not really a Sitecore question. This would probably get a better answer in webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is an opinion based question.  Sure there is a chance that users could disable the cookies in their browser, which would hinder the ability for Sitecore to gather information about that user across their journey on your site.  But the question seems to ask should there be a message? That is opinion based.  I personally don't think it matters.

Answer (score 1):

There are really 2 questions here. So lets deal with each of them:

### 1. Should I display a cookie notice?

The answer to that is not really opinion based, its a legal issue. If you run a website that is owned in the EU you *must* make sure that your website complies with the latest "cookie laws" - The law is fairly detailed, but the basics say that:

> Individuals have the right to refuse the use of cookies that reduce their online privacy

source: [The Cookie Law](https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/)

It is important to note, that if the user declines cookies - you *must* not set cookie values on your site - the user should *not* have to turn cookies off in the browser to decline them.

Another important thing to note is that only certain tracking cookies can be declined. Cookies that are essential to the "business" use of the site, can still be stored. E.g. forms auth cookies.

### 2. What will Sitecore track/do if cookies are disabled

Just because a cookie is declined or disabled, Sitecore will *still* track the user in a single session. Declining or disabling cookies does not require you to disable the tracker.

What you will lose is the ability to track anonymous users from session to session. You will not get a global session for that user.